# Custom UINavigationBar: pushItem not being called on previous iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, ios11

I made a subclass of UINavigationBar which override:

```
func pushItem(_ item: UINavigationItem, animated: Bool) {
```

When I push my first viewController on my navigationController the function get's called correctly on iOS11. 
However it's not called at all on iOS10 and lower.

Is there something that changed in iOS11 in the way `pushItem` get's called ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a known [issue](http://www.openradar.me/12197592).

To workaround this I ended up with implementing custom NavigationController to be used in pair with NavigationBar. As long as I can see only pushViewController and popToRootViewController do not work as expected. So code below covers all navigation cases for iOS 10.

**NavigationBar.swift:**

```
final class NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {
    override func pushItem(_ item: UINavigationItem, animated: Bool) {
        return transit(to: item, isNewItem: true, animated: animated) {
            super.pushItem(item, animated: animated)
        }
    }

    override func popItem(animated: Bool) -> UINavigationItem? {
        return transit(to: backItem, isNewItem: false, animated: animated) {
            super.popItem(animated: animated)
        }
    }

    override func setItems(_ items: [UINavigationItem]?, animated: Bool) {
        let isNewItem = items?.last
            .flatMap {self.items?.contains($0)}
            .map {!$0}
            ?? true
        return transit(to: items?.last, isNewItem: isNewItem, animated: animated) {
            super.setItems(items, animated: animated)
        }
    }

    func transit<T>(to item: UINavigationItem?, isNewItem: Bool, animated: Bool, action: () -> T) -> T {
        CATransaction.begin(); defer {CATransaction.commit()}
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(!animated)
        doSomeCoolAnimatedStuff(isNewItem)
        return action()
    }
}
```

**NavigationController.swift:**

```
final class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    private var baforeIos11: Bool {if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {return false} else {return true}}

    override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        guard let bar = navigationBar as? NavigationBar, baforeIos11 else {
            return super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        }
        return bar.transit(to: viewController.navigationItem, isNewItem: true, animated: true) {
            super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        }
    }

    override func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
        guard let bar = navigationBar as? NavigationBar else {
            return super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
        }
        return bar.transit(to: viewControllers.first?.navigationItem, isNewItem: false, animated: true) {
            super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to set NavigationBar delegate to self but it breaks navigation process resulting in view controllers not being popped.